# Using Authorization Code flow for a multi tenant app not working

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have 2 microsoft tenat AD tenant A and tenat B,

I need to call Azure APIs for Tenant B (like azure resource provisioning , read azure data, call cost APIs and some other azure APIs) via a app registered under Tenant A. I have implemented this via following way.

1. Created a multitenant app under tenant A (only with graph API permissions).
2. Getting azure refresh token via Authoriziation Code flow (Tenant B user(not a admin) gives consent to Tenant A app) using this URL

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code&redirect_url=authscope=openid&state=297e2e0374a6cbfb0174a73dcfce0755&nonce=c6234c0c-ab14-49f4-aa41-827061841d61

3. On successful redirection I received the refresh token.
4. When I try to use that refresh token to get Access token for "https://management.azure.com" I am getting following error.

com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: {"error_description":"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '801e6372-f223-4acb-895c-c966a0ff57c6' named 'AnkitTestMFAApp'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: 0ec48b06-64cf-47ed-b5d7-8725fba91600\r\nCorrelation ID: 96d78b24-5442-469a-a798-0f1eace171c1\r\nTimestamp: 2020-09-20 12:41:09Z","error":"invalid_grant"}
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:129)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:930)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute(AcquireTokenCallable.java:70)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute(AcquireTokenCallable.java:38)
at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalCallable.call(AdalCallable.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
I am using com.microsoft.azure.credentials.AzureTokenCredentials class to acuire token.

Even when I am using any azure java sdk function

AzureTokenCredentials credentials = our Custom Implementation of AzureTokenCredentials
Azure azure = Azure.authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(cloudAccount.getSubscriptionId());

Custom Implementation of AzureTokenCredentials

@Override
public AuthenticationResult getAccessTokenByRefreshToken(String tenantId, String resource, String refreshToken,
String clientId, String clientSecret)
throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {
AuthenticationContext authContext;
AuthenticationResult authResult;
ExecutorService service = null;
Future future;

```
    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(MessageFormat.format("{0}/{1}", "https://login.microsoftonline.com", tenantId), true,
                service);

        future = authContext.acquireTokenByRefreshToken(refreshToken, new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret),
                resource, null);

        authResult = future.get();

        return authResult;
    } finally {
        if (service != null) {
            service.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

I can see a service principle entry for this App under my Tenant B Enterprise Applications list.

What can be the possible issue? and how should be solve this?

[Asking for admin approval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3n2g.png)

[App Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLUso.png)

[Consent user settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTEcX.png)

[Conditional Access details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hszIl.png)

[Consent settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap5AE.png)

[Added Permissions As Low Risk section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QaOA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because that Tenant B user(not a admin) doesn't consent the app for scope `https://management.azure.com`.

Here are the steps to fix it.

Delete the Enterprise Application in Tenant B, it will revoke the consent.

Add permission `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` in your Azure AD app in Tenant A.

[image]

Use the following string to get code and then refresh token. When you use Tenant B user to do the user consent, you will be required to consent for `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` permission.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id={your client id}&response_mode=query&response_type=code&redirect_url=https://localhost/&scope=openid https://management.azure.com/.default&state=297e2e0374a6cbfb0174a73dcfce0755&nonce=c6234c0c-ab14-49f4-aa41-827061841d61
```

This time the refresh token will take effect because you will find the `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` permission in your Tenant B Enterprise Application.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221843/discussion-on-answer-by-allen-wu-using-authorization-code-flow-for-a-multi-tenan).